# Requesting access to multiple applications with aliases using AccountManager on Android

Tags: android, accountmanager

I'm currently succeeding in requesting access to multiple applications using AccountManager on Android but only by using an ugly authTokenType:

```
public static final String AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN_TYPE = "oauth2:https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/ https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/ https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks";
```

When my users are brought to the allow access page, it shows that ugly string above.

I want to be able to do something akin to:

```
public static final String AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN_TYPE = "Manage your calendars, Manage your tasks, Manage your contacts";
```

However, doing this leads to an error (it's combining them into one permission which doesn't exist).

How can this be done?